# Two jquery click counters working together outside the click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery below I am trying to count +1 on the counter if button1 is clicked and -1 if button2 is clicked.

In my original project the counter will then replace a JSON rest API address with that number and the search skips to the number of clicks.

```
var counter = 1; 
$("#button1").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    counter += 1

});
$("#button2").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    counter -= 1;
});
console.log(counter)
```

Comment: You won't see any effect from `console.log(counter)` unless you place it *inside* the event handlers...

Comment: That's the problem. Anny one know how to make a counter increase when you click button1 and decrease when i click button2 ?

Comment: Your code already does that. You just need to display the new counter value from inside the event handler (after you have updated the value). e.g. `$("#button1").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    counter += 1;
    $('#counter').text(counter);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working

the `console.log` should be inside the function, you can use this instead:

```js
function updated(val){
  console.log(val);
}

var counter = 1; 
$("#button1").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    counter += 1;
    // You can use console.log(counter) here, or pass the value to another function
    updated(counter);
});
$("#button2").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    counter -= 1;
    updated(counter);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) 
Now it works !.
Thanks to all of you for helping me out.
i am just at the beginning of learning to code.
Been taking courses for about 6 months - a year now.